# Performance Problem while retrieving custom objects from array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, performance, ipad

I create a custom object that has some properties like ID and Title,description etc...

And I add it to an array. (That array may contains more than 500 values).

And I use the following code to retrieve custom objects,

```
-(CustomObjects *)getObjectWithId:(int)id    {

    CustomObjects *objCustomObjects = nil;

    for (CustomObjects *customObjects in arrayCustomObjects)  {

        if (customObjects.id == id) {

            objCustomObjects = customObjects;
            break;
        }
    }


    return objCustomObjects;
}
```

But It has some performance problem, because I use the function to call on UIScrollview pinch.

**How can I improve performance in fetching the objects?**

thanks in advance,

Comment: I hope you're not actually using `id` as an parameter to your method - it's a reserved word in Objective-C... :)

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary is better for this. The only catch is that you can’t have a `NSDictionary` with primitive `int` keys, so that you have to wrap the `id` in an `NSNumber`.

```
- (void) addCustomObject: (CustomObject*) obj {
    NSNumber *wrappedID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[obj idNumber]];
    [dictionary setObject:obj forKey:wrappedID];
}

- (CustomObject*) findObjectByID: (int) idNumber {
    NSNumber *wrappedID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[obj idNumber]];
    return [dictionary objectForKey:wrappedID];
}
```

A dictionary (also called [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)) does not have to go through all the values to find the right one, it has all the values arranged cleverly according to the keys so that it can jump to the right one or close to it. What you are doing with the array is called [linear search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search) and it’s not very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Better you can use `NSDictionary` with `id` as the key. You can easily fetch the object from the dictionary.

Is it Ok for your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an NSPredicate that checks whether `id` equals the one you're looking for, and simply filter the custom objects using this predicate by calling `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`.

To improve performance, I would try to postpone whatever you're trying to calculate by not directly calling the function that does the heavy work in your scroll view, but rather call `[self performSelector:... withObject:nil afterDelay:0];` which postpones the calculation to the next runloop cycle. If you check if there's already a calculation scheduled before you call performSelector you should actually be able to reduce the frequency of the calculation while maintaining a crisp interface.

Answer (score 0):

You must ditch the array in favor for a dictionary if you want to have fast lookups.

If you want to access objects both by key and index then you need to the objects around in two collections, and make sure they are in sync.

I have already done a helper class for this named `CWOrderedDictionary`. It's a subclass of `NSMutableDictionary` that allows for access to objects by both keys **(as any dictionary do)**, and by index using methods identical to `NSMutableArray`.

My class is available to use for inspiration or as is from here: https://github.com/jayway/CWFoundation/

Answer (score -1):

Use NSPredicate:-

You will receive the filtered array with the object that has the id you passed;

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %@", id];

NSArray *filtered = [arrayCustomObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

Comment: The predicate thing can’t really do anything smarter than the linear search he’s already doing, can it?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `int`just use `[NSNumber numberWithInt:]` , i did some changes in your given code.

```
-(CustomObjects *)getObjectWithId:(NSNumber* )id    {//changed int to NSNumber

    CustomObjects *objCustomObjects = nil;

    NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.id==%@",id];
    NSArray *result = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bPredicate];
//return filtered array contains the object of your given value

    if([result count]>0)
        objCustomObjects = [result objectAtIndex:0];

    }
    return objCustomObjects;
}
```

Comment: Again, do you feel that `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` can do anything smarter than the linear search the poster is already doing? Did you profile the code? It has to be slower than the original version.